# Ajax request with JavaScript responds with 302 (Found)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send data by Ajax with the Post method, but the answer gives me `302 (Found)` and I do not know what it can be. This is my code:

```
function sendData(){

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } else { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log("Response" + xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "request.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("name="+document.getElementById('username').value);

}
```

and my .php file only print a message

```
<?php echo 'hello : ' . $_POST["name"] ?>
```

Comment: You should try jQuery once. It has lot simpler syntax.

Comment: did you set the Location `header()` in `request.php`  or set the status code manually `http_response_code(302)` ? both are going to cause `302` response

Answer (score 0):

The **[302 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)** indicates that the resource you are requesting has redirected to another resource. If this is behind some authentication, or requiring a session to be active then yes, it would follow that the session timing out is responsible for the ajax resource being called to redirect to possibly a login screen maybe.

Try to use jQuery request, as it much simpler - also recommended in the above comments!

Comment: I do not like using JQuery. only Native @Saumya Rastogi

Answer (score 0):

One way to get such a message is, to forget to add a `/` to the end of a URL, which is a "sub-directory" of the document root. As the URL `your.domain/whatever` and `your.domain/whatever/` might not be the same. (Depending on server configuration, and the actual application serving those URLs.)

I can see, in this case you are actually POSTing to `/request.php`, so this might not apply, but just in case, I'd try to make that request 'by hand' and see what happens.

There are many browser plugins, that let you generate AJAX queries.